# Printing ListBox Values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a code that takes selected values from a listbox, and prints them onto a new worksheet while multiplying the one of the numbers in the ListBox data. My code is printing incorrectly and is giving me a mismatch error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Me.ListBox1.List = Range("B7:F22").Value


    
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Integer
Dim Q As Variant
Dim Msg As Variant


For x = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
If Me.ListBox1.Selected(x) Then
Load Me

End If
Next x

End Sub


Private Sub CompleteForm_Click()
Dim y As Integer

    Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Sheets.count) 'Creates new worksheet for part order form
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Part Order Form" 'Rename new sheet
    Range("A1").Value = "Part Number"
    Range("B1").Value = "Part Name"
    Range("C1").Value = "QtY."
    Range("A2").Value = ListBox1.List(x)
    Me.TextBox2.Value = y
    Range("C2").Value = y * ListBox1.List(x)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you intend the value of `x` to be in `CompleteForm_Click`?

Comment: As @BigBen pointed out, the lifetime of the variable called 'x' in the **CommandButton1_Click()** event lasts till the end of the event. (End Sub). In the **CompleteForm_Click()** event your x variable is not defined.

Comment: ...which means, if that code runs at all, that `Option Explicit` is missing from the top of your modules.

Comment: Also `y` isn't being assigned and will always have a value of `0`, and `Load Me` is useless because `Me` is definitely already loaded by the time that instruction runs.

Comment: @BigBen The x would be the count as it steps through each selected item on the list. How would I define x so that it can populate each selected list item to the new worksheet?

Comment: Well you'd need a loop?

Comment: @BigBen yes I have a for loop in my code, is the for loop incorrect?

Comment: Well, you don't actually have a for loop in `CompleteForm_Click` though, right?

Comment: @BigBen Yes correct, I wanted the for loop to run while printing the selected listbox items to a new worksheet (hence adding the x variable to count each listbox item) I tried keeping it all within one For loop, but the code would print incorrectly